# Geoder.getFromLocationName doesn't give the same results as maps.google.nl

Tags: android, google-geocoder

First of all: Geocoder is present and works fine on my android application. It gives results for the examples from the android documentation:
"Dalvik, Iceland", an address such as "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA", an airport code such as "SFO", etc..

But when I search a restaurant or something like that in my own country, the Netherlands, geocoder won't find anything. But if I type the same query string into maps.google.nl it gives me directly the restaurant I was looking for.

I already have tried to restrict the geocoder within two long/lat points, but that doesn't make any difference. So it seems that I can find anything in de US easily, but finding a location of a restaurant in the Netherlands doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Geocoding API](http://Google%20Maps%20API%20v3%20Geocoder%20Tool) (which I think is what your Android app is querying) will only return geographical features, not business listings. Those are available on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/) because that's an application and uses more search backends than the Geocoding API.

Appending the country name won't help, what you'll get in your Android app (using the geocoder) is the same you will get from the [Google Maps API v3 Geocoder Tool](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html). It does include some POIs, but not all business listings (restaurants, hotels, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had a similar problem with UK adresses, I believe it's because the web app has more context than just the portion of the map you're looking at (like which countries are in view).

If I recall correctly, I solved it by appending ", UK" or ", GB" (or ", United Kingdom" / ", Great Britain") to all queries, so in your case try appending ", Netherlands".

Comment: Thank you Joaquim. Just tried it but it makes no difference. Calling geocoder.getFromLocationName("bruintje beer, Netherlands") gives me no result. But typing the exact same string into maps.google.com (the US version) gives me my location. Only complete correct spelled addresses in the Netherlands are find such as "Street, City, Country"

Comment: I also tried the this function: getFromLocationName (String locationName, int maxResults, double lowerLeftLatitude, double lowerLeftLongitude, double upperRightLatitude, double upperRightLongitude), to restrict the search area. But that makes no difference

Comment: Hmm that's too bad, out of ideas then.